# C Programming : Codeblocks stops working with C till I make a tiny change. Any idea why?

Tags: c, codeblocks

The code is included below: 
When I run the program with the line `printf(ch)` it says project could not be executed. However when I use the placeholder, the project works just fine. Any idea why it is such?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[10];
    printf("Enter a password. \n");
    scanf("%s",arr );
   // printf(arr);
    char ch;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
       ch=arr[i];

       printf(ch);
       //printf("%c",ch);--> if i use this instead of printf(ch) it works fine. Can this please be explained

    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you're giving an incorrect argument to `printf`. The first arg needs to be a `const char *` whereas you gave it a `char`. What did you expect or what are you trying to prove? Just stick with the second (commented out) `printf` call instead.

Comment: If your compiler does not report an error in the line `printf(ch);`, drop it right away and look for a competent compiler.

Comment: Did you read documentation of [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)? Reading it would have been faster than asking here. And compile with all warnings & debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`; see also [putchar(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putchar.3.html)

Comment: You need to locate the "compiler messages" window in your IDE and watch it. If you have any errors or warnings, fix them before trying to run your program.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `printf` expects the argument should be in the `const char*, ...` as input argument while

```
char ch;
```

is not of pointer type

So you "can" do:

```
char ch = 'A';
printf(&ch); //this is bad because not only it is not well-formatted but also, though compiled, may cause undefined behavior. This is to only show you the idea
```

but cannot do:

```
char ch = 'A';
printf(ch);
```

Edited (after `paddy`'s correction):

The correct way to print it using `printf` is by using the print format provided for character,

```
char ch = 'A';
printf("%c", ch);
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Understood it

Comment: @ShravanNiranjan Great! =)

Comment: Not only is `printf(&ch);` "not really good", it is _undefined behaviour_.  Do **not** do this!!  Use `printf( "%c", ch );`.

Comment: @paddy Hi, paddy. I only mean to point out the concept that it should be a pointer as an argument. But if you can help to improve the answer, kindly edit. I will edit my answer too...

Comment: I think it would have been better to explain why the formatted version that the OP asked about is actually correct by briefly explaining how it works, rather than offering reckless code that just happens to compile.

Comment: @paddy I edited my answer, based on your correction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect when you lie to the compiler? :-)

The `printf` function's prototype, declared in `<stdio.h>` is

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

which means the first argument must be given and it must be of type *pointer-to-char*.
If instead you pass printf a `char` then that is mis-interpreted as a pointer-to-char, causing **undefined behavior** in C lingo.

Speak the truth to the compiler and it will cooperate. Finding out about the truth starts with reading the documentation of the library functions you use and enabling all warnings your compiler offers. This particular one is easily caught by almost all modern compilers.

PS: using proper terminology also helps communicating problems. What you call *placeholder* is called *argument* or, more specifically, *format*.